# A scenario-checking console application

Tags: c++, vector

I am developing a scenario-checking console application for a game similar to chess where the player can make finitely many moves in 1 turn.
I'm writing it in C++ because it is said that it is the fastest language.
The main goal of the program is to output the best scenario out of all the checked ones.
The only solution that comes to my mind is by using vectors to store all the possible scenarios.
In a while loop each scenario will "beget" its possible scenarios until there are no more new scenarios to be created and then the loop ends.

Here's a quick sketch of my code:

```cpp
class Game
{

public:
    //possible moves

    bool Move1();
    bool Move2();
    ...
}

vector <Game> Scenarios;

void Try(Game g)
{
    int step = 0; // the index for the current scenario
        Game g1; // scenario which will copy the current scenario
        Scenarios.push_back(g); // pushing the initial scenario

    while(step < Scenarios.size())
    {
        g1 = Scenarios[step]; // copying the current scenario

        if(g1.Move1()) Scenarios.push_back(g1); // executing the first possible move

        g1 = Scenarios[step]; // copying the current scenario again

        if(g1.Move2()) Scenarios.push_back(g1); // executing the second possible move
        ...
            
        step++; // the index increases to continue to the next scenario
    }
}
```

What I'm asking is: Are there any better ways to approach this type of problem?
I don't have a clear understanding of how backtracking algorithms work.
P.S. Sorry for writing the word "scenario" so frequently :)

Comment: OT, but if you're "writing it in C++ because it is said that it is the fastest language" then you have selected poorly.  These kind of things seldom depend on language alone. Unless it's for some kind of assignment and you're required to use a specific language or library, always go with what you're comfortable with, what you know the best. And I'm sorry to say that your "quick sketch" shows some lack of knowledge of C++ to fully utilize it. I also think you need to go through your requirements, analysis and design another few iterations.

Comment: Thank you, sir. Should I use JavaScript then?

Comment: If that's your usual language, that you feel most comfortable with and knows the best, then yes. I think it will be plenty fast for your requirements.

Comment: FYI: [Make It Work Make It Right Make It Fast](https://wiki.c2.com/?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast) If you're comfortable in JavaScript you might write an implementation in this language first. Once you got it running and are satisfied with the outcome you still could consider it to C++. (Maybe, you're even that satisfied that you don't see any need for this anymore.) Additionally, I personally like to have a reference project to explore a new programming technique or language. Nevertheless, you have to be carefully not to port your existing code too literally.

Comment: Please see [ask] and ask yourself why your title advertises running in the console, while your question is about algorithms.

Comment: BTW, "C++ because it is said that it is the fastest language" - Programs written (properly) in C++ will run fast so that's true. You pay for it with longer development times. If "fast" is to mean "time to market" then the statement is wrong. Just speaking from a general perspective, exceptions do exist.

Comment: One trick that these computer opponents use is to eliminate as many possible paths as possible.  The problem with chess is the quantity of moves (using a brute-force) method.  For example, the computer would not check the castle piece for an opening move because the castle can't move (it's blocked in all possible paths).

Comment: Search the internet for "game minimax tree".  Also check out [gamedev.se].